# JSON compress JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, json, compression

Good morning everyone,
I have a problem with a project, and I could use your help.
In this project I send data in JSON form with the following structure:

```
{success: true, 
 descriptor: {
   {x: 181, y: 576, data: Array(32)},
   {x: 85, y: 45, data: Array(32)},
   ...
 }
}
```

The total size of the data sent is close to 35Kb. I would like to reduce it as much as possible. I tried to go through some library like msgpack, gzip, pako, and algos like lzw or passing Uint8Array.
Except that I recover data in python on my server, and the library doubles the weight of my project, so the compression ratio/project size is not interesting.

Do you have any ideas about an effective method?
Thanks in advance for your help...

Comment: Hi! you send data from javascript in the browser to a python backend? or the other way around?

Comment: from javascript in the browser to a python backend ^^

Comment: do you need to send it too many times? or is it a one off per user? if you send it a lot, does it change much between submissions or does it tend to be the same with a few amendments?

Comment: It may be sent often.
However the structure always remains the same with the same number of values in the tables.
However the values are constantly different

Comment: there's not much you can do, make `data` -> `d` will save some space. Is it a real problem, tho? 35kb does't seem that much. Is it for a web expected to run in a phone? while on the street? desktop? stable connexion?

Comment: it is for run in a phone on the street I would like to send the smallest possible packages to save bandwidth